# Opening Kendo popup window for adding new records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, popup, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an separate Add button (neither on toolbar, nor on grid) and I want to open a popup window (having some fields) after clicking this button in order to create a new record. I have a look at the Kendo Demo pages, but all the samples use grid's or toolbar's Create button. Instead of them, a need a sample with a separate button. Any sample please?

Update: I want to create a listview as shown below instead of grid:

[image]

Comment: You said you were not using grid, then what you have used?

Comment: Yes, I do not use grid. I just show record cy hyperlink and there will be an Add button on that page. Whenever I click Add button, I open a poupup and enter the data of new record.

Comment: then it should be a list right? have you try look at list view widget?

Comment: ListView could do the trick but it does not have built-in sorting mechanism which seems to be found of your desired solution.

Comment: Ok, what about using a kendo grid? Can I customize it as shown on the picture?

Answer (score 2):

If you call dataGrid.addRow() method and edit mode is set to "popup", Popup window will be displayed.

Look at this [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EJOgA)

Comment: Thanks, but I need an example not using grid. Assume that there is no grid on the page, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: Any help please regarding to the last status?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why don't you use Kendo UI Window to show create form for user, collect user form data and send it to server by Ajax. Take a look at the Kendo UI Window sample. Kendo UI window content can be loaded by ajax too.

Comment: I updated my code. I need a listview or grid as shown on the image.

Comment: Your sample seems to be OK, but only the grid fields are created on the popup dialog. What if I want to create other field of the data model on the dialog? In that case should I hide them like that: { field: "xxx", hidden: "true" }